# Jquery sortable serialized value to sinatra

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, sinatra, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm currently trying to resort a list with the help of Jquery sortable and my sinatra app. Just have one question. The serialize function of sortable generates a string with the new order of the list like this:

```
"id[]=15&id[]=16&id[]=14&id[]=17&id[]=18"
```

When I post that to the server over ajax my Sinatra app understands it as a string. My question is, how do I convert that string to something in sinatra that I can loop thru?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it!

Instead of using "serialize" on the JS side of things i used "toArray". Then I could easily loop thru the array on the sinatra side. Here:s the JS code:

```
$('.sortable').sortable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
        start = $(ui.item).index();
    },
    update: function( event, ui ) {

        item = $(ui.item).attr('id');
        end = $(ui.item).index();

        var sorted = $('.sortable').sortable("toArray");

        $.post("/items/order", { order: sorted } );

        console.log (sorted);
    }
});
```